# Error log about wrong font while I create JLabel on Mac

Tags: java, swing, fonts, jlabel, macos-monterey

When I create a new JLabel, I get the following error log in the console:

> Warning: the fonts "Times" and "Times" are not available for the Java
> logical font "Serif", which may have unexpected appearance or
> behavior. Re-enable the "Times" font to remove this warning.

But I do not use this (default) font.

How can I solve this problem or at least suppress the message?

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
// sb gets some text here
// ...
JLabel label = new JLabel();
label.setFont(new Font("Classic Console Neue", Font.PLAIN, 18)); // changed font to a valid font
label.setText(sb.toString()); // this line will cause the log entry, but why?
```

A workaround would be to install the Times.ttf on every target computer, but that is not practicable.

Comment: Where do you see this warning? Can you post the warning message in it's original by a screenshot or something?

Comment: It is in the Eclipse console window in red text

Comment: Can you try adding `@SupressWarnings("all")`

Comment: Can't I change the default font anywhere?

Comment: What versions of Java and macOS?

Comment: As discussed in [this article](https://blogs.oracle.com/javamagazine/post/its-time-to-move-your-applications-to-java-17-heres-why-and-heres-how) in Oracle’s *Java Magazine*, Java 11 and later no longer bundles fonts with the JVM. But those removed fonts may have been [only Lucida fonts](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/11-relnote-issues.html#JDK-8191522).

Comment: Is Classic Console Neue installed on the machine and available in the list of fonts known to Java?

Comment: Yes, this font works fine. I talk about the default font `Times`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Swing I did not find a way to define another default font, but for components (e.g. JLabel, I found one:

```
UIManager.put("Label.font", new Font("Courier New", Font.PLAIN, 12));
```

Comment: This doesn't resolve the warning.

Comment: @AlexeyIvanov It was a workaround

Comment: Workaround for what? It changes the default font for `JLabel` and nothing more. The warning is still printed.

Comment: @AlexeyIvanov I didn't get the warning anymore

Answer (score 2):

The "Times" font is not installed in macOS 12 Monterey.

Java has been updated to take this into account, newer versions of Java should not print the warning and should correctly use a serif font. See [JDK-8273358](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8273358) for more details.